# http request with javascript for JSON object in a locally hosted API

Tags: javascript, json, api, httpwebrequest, localhost

I have a API running on my machine locally written in sinatra and jruby which interacts with a sql server. Now, 'localhost:4567/get/233310/loc' returns a JSON object

```
[{"uid":233307,"lat":41.4191113333333,"long":-72.8941905}]
```

What I want to do, for now is get this JSON object and assign each of the object to a variable in my javascript..which I think would best done with a http request? (if there's a better way..please do let me know).

Eventually, I need this to make the request every 30 secs but I will deal with that later.

Can anyone help me with this??

Thank you.

Comment: This is a standard XMLHttpRequest (AJAX) call.  Read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest), then add specifics to your question if needed.  Make sure everything is on the same domain.  Also, you may find a library like jQuery helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful library is called Prototype.  Read about it here:

http://www.prototypejs.org/

The code to make a request like this in Prototype is really easy.  Just include the prototype.js library on your page:

```
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
```

Then run this code:

var url = 'http://localhost:4567/get/233310/loc';
  new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method: 'get',
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
          var json = transport.responseJSON;
          window.alert(json.inspect());
        }
      });

When this completes, you should see a pop up alert with the contents of your JSON object displayed.

Your server side script should serve up the JSON with the HTTP header "Content-Type" set to "application/json" so that the client side script code understands that it should try to parse it as JSON.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I tried the code and it worked(kinda). It is communicating with the API running on my local host. But I get two errors:1) XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4567/get/233310/loc. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.AND, 2)
2Refused to get unsafe header "X-JSON".

Also my server side script is written in Jruby(Sinatra). So any ideas?